# AVAudioSession for Audio Video call

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession

I am implementing Audio Video Call like feature. I am using AVAudioSession for Voice feature. I want to configure the AVAudioSession such that it should work on the receive speaker and loud speaker as well as the headphones.I am using the following initialisation for AVAudioSession:

```
NSError *err = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                         withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&err];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&err];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat error:&err];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: NULL];
```

The above code works fine for loud speaker and headphones but the voice quality from loud speaker is very low.

I have tried the code below for switching the audio route to receiver speaker. But it doesn't work.

```
NSError *err = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&err];
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve this question? I have exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem.i solve it by

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];

NSArray *outputs =[[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute] outputs];
BOOL haveSpeaker = NO;

for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *currentPut in outputs) {
    if ([currentPut.portType isEqualToString:@"Speaker"]) {
        haveSpeaker = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if (haveSpeaker) {

    NSError *error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

In my opinion AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultNone is not reciver,it's default route. so u hava changed the default route for this mode;